# New App I created not Working receiving a error

Tags: facebook

Why am i receiving this error, when trying to access my app? and what do i need to do to correct.

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

thanks for your assistance
Robert

Comment: My guess is that you are using login on a url that you not specified in the settings

Comment: @ Wizkid thanks, which setting?

Comment: One that it mentioned in the error message

Answer (score 0):

Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/
Click on "apps" > "settings" > "add platform"

That's how you setup where your application will live. Inside the Settings you can also add "App Domains" which specifies which domains are allowed to use your app.

cheers,